# Taking a C header with multiple structs to Java

Tags: java, c

I'm trying to port code written in C over to Java and starting out with some header files. Some header files contain `#define`s and multiple `typedef struct`s

I'm not sure how to go about taking this over to Java. Would each `struct` require a new Java class file? Can I encapsulate the whole header file into a single class?

And to retrieve members of a struct I'd need to create getter/setter methods? Any easier way?

Thanks

Comment: Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: you could use a global class and define your structures as subclasses inside this class. But doing this is good only if you're going to use the structures in this class, because you cannot create them from the outside.

Comment: 1. Java have no structures, you can use POJO classes instead 2. In any case porting C code to Java can be painful, since language difference - you can try to use JNI to simply use C code inside java.

Comment: Structs are not necessarily compatible to Java classes. The C code might assume a certain memory layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java supports any nesting of classes and inner classes.
Top level, independent classes are generally declared in their own file. 
If you nest classes you can make them static in order to be able to use them without creating an implicit reference to the outer class.
Otherwise and depending on your model and usage using non-static inners may create inflated memory consumption and unintended consequences.

Examples:

Simple top level class:

```
public class A {
    public String text;
    public String moreText;
}

//Create an instance of the above:
A a = new A();
//property access for public properties requires no getters/setters from within or without the package
a.text = "Hello";
a.moreText = "World";
boolean b = "Hello".equals(a.text); //true
```

Static nested class:

```
public class A {
    public String text;
    public String moreText;
    public static class B {
        public int i;
    }
}

//Create an instance of B:
A.B b = new A.B();
//property access for public properties requires no getters/setters from within or without the package
b.i = 5;
//Note that no instance of A is actually created
```

Non-static nested/inner class:

```
public class A {
    public String text;
    public String moreText;
    public class B {
        public B(String text) {
            A.this.text = text;
        }
        public int i;
        public A getA() {
            return A.this;
        }
    }
}
A.B b = new A.B("Hello");
System.out.println(b.getA().text); // Hello
```

Note how the above creates an implicit instance of `A`, whose text is set to "Hello" in `B`'s constructor. An explicit accessor for that A is needed to be able to access it.

These are some very crude examples. Nesting of classes (static or otherwise) is a design choice that may depend on your goals for encapsulation. Depending on the context it may make more sense to keep a static nested class nested instead of declaring it in its own file, but both are valid.

Using visibility levels of public vs private, protected or package (none) is another choice, but as you go into inheritance, you will find that getter/setter access is usually preferred. What's more, any decent IDE will be happy to generate them for you, so the effort of typing them up doesn't factor in. It's solely about whether direct property access or getters/setters are more appropriate for your object model (or indeed an individual class).

Since it isn't feasible to reproduce everything here, I suggest you delve into the tutorials, such as the one on [Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Edit:
Top level classes aren't `static`. Thanks @Wyzard.

Comment: The `static` modifier isn't used on top-level classes, only on nested classes.

Comment: Good point, actually.